# MKMapView Setting Initial Zoom level

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming

I use this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews to set the initial region of my map.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.747266, 100.526804);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startCoord, 800, 800)];
[self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
NSLog(@"%f",adjustedRegion.span.latitudeDelta);
```

However, the initial zoom level doesn't work. The coordinate is correct, but it always zoom in to probably the max level. I check the span of the region and got 0.0. How do I fix this.

Comment: Use setSpan: property to the self.mapView

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set your span.So give your span value here.

```
adjustedRegion.span.longitudeDelta  = 0.005;
adjustedRegion.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.005;
```

Comment: I'm just asking if MkCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance should do it automatically, or my understanding is wrong. That's all...

Comment: I think your visible distance is small.So please  make it long.

Answer (score 1):

Custom span setting:

```
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.04;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.04;
```

else programmatically:

```
region.span.longitudeDelta = geoMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
region.span.latitudeDelta = geoMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
```